# Form submission results in Error 404 in PHP and XAMPP

Tags: php, html, forms, visual-studio-code, xampp

So, I am new to PHP and the main problem is that I was learning and following the lectures and I did exactly what the instructor did but I've got different results and before I show my code, this is my project's directory:

[image]

This is my code: The instructor said that if we leave the action = "" blank, the form gets processed by this current file and that is what I want to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PHP Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PHP Forms</h1>
    
    <form action="get" method="" name="">

        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "txtUsername" value = ""/>
        <br/><br/>

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "txtUserEmail" value = ""/>
        <br/><br/>

        <label>List:</label>
        <select name = "selMember">
            <option value = "Please select">Please select</option>
            <option value = "Joey">Joey</option>
            <option value = "Rachel">Rachel</option>
            <option value = "Chandler">Chandler</option>
            <option value = "Monica">Monica</option>
            <option value = "Phoebe">Phoebe</option>
            <option value = "Ross">Ross</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>

        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name = "subForm" /> 

    </form>

    <h2>User submitted data:</h2>
    <?php 
        $username = $_GET['txtUsername'];
        $userEmail = $_GET['txtUserEmail'];
        $selectedMember = $_GET['selMember'];
        echo "Username: $username <br/>";
        echo "User's email: $userEmail <br/>";
        echo "User's selected member: $selectedMember <br/>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So this is the form: Please ignore the warning notices as the instructor said he will teach how to handle it on the next video.
[image]

And this is the result after form submission:
[image]

The problem is that the form gets submitted to this URL:
"http://localhost:8080/php_code/get?txtUsername=anyone123&txtUserEmail=anyone%40gmail.com&selMember=Rachel&subForm=Submit"

The URL should be submitted to "http://localhost:8080/php_code/phpForms.php..." instead of "http://localhost:8080/php_code/...".

So, if I manually type in the right URL:
"http://localhost:8080/php_code/phpForms.php/get?txtUsername=anyone123&txtUserEmail=anyone%40gmail.com&selMember=Rachel&subForm=Submit",
The form submission works just like the instructors:
[image]

So, how can I fix this problem? Am I placing my files in the wrong directory?

Comment: Form method should be get/post and action should be "". You are doing the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form tag like this.

```
 <form action="" method="get" name="">
  .......
 </form>
```

Comment: OMG I made such a simple mistake! Thank you for helping me.